# Adding values with same frequency in time series with pandas:

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas `DataFrame` indexed by `pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex` and I'd like to add new values starting from the last date in the series. I need that each new value inserted be in the next date using a daily frequency.

```
Example:
            TotalOrders
Date                   
2013-12-29         3756
2013-12-30         6222
2013-12-31         4918
```

I'd like to insert, let's say, `5000` and that it will be automatically assigned to date `2014-01-01` and so on for the following values. What would be the best way to do that?

```
Example:
            TotalOrders
Date                   
2013-12-29         3756
2013-12-30         6222
2013-12-31         4918
2014-01-01         5000
```

Comment: so if there's 1 order in  on 2014-01-02 total orders would read 5001 for that date but 2013-12-31 preserves 5000, correct?

Comment: No. What I meant is that I should assign new orders with, let's say, some method (like .addNextDate(5028) and a new column would appear like 2014-01-02 with TotalOrders of 5028. I'm wondering what is the simplest way to do that without having to create a full index, join the DataFrames and then add the values.

Comment: then user's answer is what you need :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `loc` with `DateOffset`:

```
df.loc[df.index.max()+pd.DateOffset(1)] = 5000
```

```
            TotalOrders
Date
2013-12-29         3756
2013-12-30         6222
2013-12-31         4918
2014-01-01         5000
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!